# Use accessor mutator's within Laravel 4 lists method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mutators

I have a simple mutator:

```
public function getFullnameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->first_name. ' ' .$this->last_name;
}
```

But I also have a method that returns a list of specific users for use in a select input:

```
static function getDeliveryManagers()
{
    return User::IsDeliveryManager()->lists('first_name', 'id');
}
```

I need that array returned to be ['First Name Last Name', 'id']

But the mutator doesn't work, e.g.

```
return User::IsDeliveryManager()->lists('Fullname', 'id');
```

I found this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/668

Which Taylor marks as being done but I cant get it working. Using Laravel 4.2.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `lists()` on `Eloquent Collection`. So make sure `IsDeliveryManager()` is returning correct values. Its better if you can share the code of `IsDeliveryManager()`. If its is `query scope` you need to call `get()` before `lists()`.

```
return User::IsDeliveryManager()->get()->lists('fullname', 'id');
```

Comment: Sorted with the get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The mutator, even if it is in camelcase, should be called in lowercase.

So you should be calling it as such:

```
return User::IsDeliveryManager()->lists('fullname', 'id');
```

Comment: Yeah tried that as soon as posted the question but same error. It looks for the field name of 'fullname'

Comment: it makes no difference if you start with lowercase or capital case. Although its better you start with lower but both gives correct result.